# Simple way to bind two different properties together?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

In my application I always want `hscrollbar.LargeChange` to equal `panel.Width`. Currently I set `hscrollbar.LargeChange` to `panel.Width`in resizing events, painting events, et cetera. I do not know much about binding so I'm wondering if it is possible to do this.

Sorry if this is a simple question but when I tried googling binding and c# I got a lot of complicated information about other platforms.

Comment: Binding is typically associated with WPF - I think you're OOL on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to bind the LargeChange property of the HScrollBar to the Width property of the panel, but I think I've just discovered a bug in .NET 4 with regards to this as it works if I target .NET 3.5.

Basically, you need to manually create a Binding object and assign it to the HScrollBar's DataBindings collection, like so:

```
hScrollBar1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("LargeChange", panel1, "Size.Width", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Again, this doesn't work in .NET 4, but it does in .NET 3.5. I'll probably submit a bug report.

Cheers

Comment: Added bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684580/simple-binding-between-control-properties-stopped-working-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way you are doing it, in the panel.Resize event is the only way to do it in windows forms.